# Google не поддерживает расширения для программы Internet Download Manager

Tags: компоненты

я пользуюсь этой программой уже лет 10,но браузер Google,начиная с 73 версии перестал поддерживать,как только вы ее устанавливаете-все работает,но как только вы выключите комп.-после включения расширение исчезает.

Answer (score 0):

задите `C:\Пользователи\("ваше юзер")\appdata\local\Google\User Data\Default\Extensions` смотрите там ваше расширение ест или нет

Comment: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\User Data\Default\Extensions